# Intellij run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I am new to programming and first time using Intellij IDE.
I currently have four drivers as picture is shown, is there any way I can run the driver without manually clicking each driver on each time I run?
When I used Eclipse IDE, each class runs automatically even if I switch back and forth to different drivers. With Intellij, I have to go back to run configuration and click the class I want to run instead of running it automatically.

Comment: did you try to configure the whole project while creating it for the first time?

Comment: @Aladin I am not quite sure if I am getting your point...

Comment: what are you trying to run , it's just a java project right ? If not you can take a look on it. https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/tutorial-your-first-java-application/

Comment: Just java project

Comment: try to follow the video on this link , i think it will solve your problem

Comment: The video only has one class to run, I have 4 classes that I can run. So I am wondering if  there is any way I can just run the class that I want to run instead of manually going to the configuration and choose the class

Comment: Basically , if you configured your project you can add as many classes you want it will be doable to run each one without having a problem

Comment: There should be green play button in runnable class - you may click it. Also it will create temporary run configuration for each class.